# Use groupby function and keep first value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a data table which consists of a column that contains a product name and then two columns with values. The first column contains a value that seldom changes (column B). The next column contains many different values (column C).

First, I would like to sort based on product name and then I would like to keep the first unique value of column B. My data is also time dependent so if the same value appears more than once after a new value, then I would like to keep the value again.

´´´
dt = {'col1': [A,A,A,B,B,B,C,B,C,A,A], 'col2': [2.1,2.1,2.1,4,4,4,3.4,5,6,2.1,2.1], 'col3':[2.1,2.3,2.5,4,4.1,4.2,3.4,5,6,2.1,2.2]
´´´

Ideally this should look like a datatable like this

´´´
dt = {'col1': [A,B,C,B,C,A], 'col2': [2.1,4,4,3.4,5,6,2.1], 'col3':[2.1,4,3.4,5,6,2.1]

Comment: IIUC `df[ df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())]`

Comment: Or `out = df[df[['col1','col2']].ne(df[['col1','col2']].shift()).any(axis=1)]`